# Neural Network Input Layer (Should inputs go to all neurons?)

Tags: neural-network

[image]
[image]

Between these two setups, is there any difference in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in performance. The fully connected network (the right image) can generalize on inputs the left one cannot.